# Improve performance of a join between a varchar field and a substring applied to another field

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have a MySQL varchar field with values like these:

```
'00007_1'
'00016_1'
'00016_2'
'00231_1'
'00326_3'
```

I'm looking for the best way to put this field in join with another table with a varchar field with values like these (I list those that match previous):

```
'7'
'16'
'16'
'231'
'326'
```

This is how I've made:

```
SELECT *
FROM   R
INNER JOIN RC ON Trim(leading '0' from Substring(R.N_DEN,1,instr(R.N_DEN,'_')-1)) = RC.N_DEN
```

Anybody knows if there is a quicker and better performace solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a derived column with values pre-derived in the joining table. However there will be a space trade-off.

Comment: I need a trigger to mantain updated the derived field, isn't it?

Comment: There are multitudes of options available. Trigger is not recommended solution here. Triggers has a lot of performance issues in many databases and not generally recommended. The Derived column should be populated by the code that populates this table everytime a insert/update(only if the concerned column is updated) is made on the table. One other approach will be to build another table periodically joining this two tables. But this depends on factors like how frequently you query these two tables and how frequently these tables are updated.